# Taking ownership of a variable in a function mutably

Tags: rust

Is it possible to take a mutable ownership of a variable and if so how? Here is an example of what I mean (it does not compile):

```
fn read_all_input<I: Iterator<u8>>(dont_use_after: mut I) -> SuperReturn {
  //This function will consume all the iterator and therefore wants to TAKE it away
  //from the user, not borrow it.
}

fn main() {
  //Somehow get an iter.
  let mut myIter = ...;
  //Pass it to the function.
  read_all_input(myIter);
  //Make the compiler cry here.
  let x = myIter.next();
}
```

I know I can take a mutable reference but I would prefer to move the iterator into the function and doing so MUTABLY (for loops require mutable iterators of course).

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. The signature should read:

```
fn read_all_input<I: Iterator<u8>>(mut dont_use_after: I) -> SuperReturn {
//                                 ^^^
```

Inherited mutability goes on the binding/pattern, not on the type. There's a `mut` in `&mut T` because the mutability there is not inherited.

Comment: All right thanks! Do you know if the variable is guaranteed to move or is there a chance it gets copied instead?

Comment: @Phil, `I` is generic type, so by default it will be moved, because `I` does not have `Copy` bound. You could add it: `I: Iterator<u8>+Copy`, though I doubt it will be useful - I think, there are few iterators which are implicitly copyable. And there is no such thing as chance here - the value is either moved or copied, depending on the variable type.

Comment: @Phil Also note that the copy/move distinction is a semantic difference (it affects compiler analysis and perhaps where `drop` calls are inserted), it doesn't affect the performance characteristics or the code for the parameter passing or assignment. Both moves and copies are bitwise copies under the hood (think `memcpy`).

Comment: @delnan Wouldn't copying introduce a supplementary destructor, i.e. 1 in the caller and 1 in the callee, instead of just 1 in the callee?

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Are you saying that if I don't require Copy in the type constraint than **it will be** moved? Or is it really just type dependant? If so, is there a way to force the move? Thanks!

Comment: @Phil Types that implement `Drop` are not `Copy`. Such types must implement `Clone` to be copyable, and users must call `.clone()` explicitly to copy (unlike in C++ where the copy constructor can be invoked implicitly). Therefore, there's no risk of having the destructor run twice (on two separate objects) because the compiler decided to copy rather than move.